# Display git commit statistics in bash

Tags: performance, bash, git

I have scripts to display [commit statistics](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/fd1a5109daf6738ca505ede13f2cddb84743b44e/links/bin/git-cstat#L1) and [merge statistics](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/fd1a5109daf6738ca505ede13f2cddb84743b44e/links/bin/git-mstat#L1) of my repos, and they work. I wrote them for my personal usage, and because I was interested in finding trends in my git repos.

This script reports statistics about commits (number, average length in words, etc.). Relevant commits can be selected using `git-rev-list` options.

Features and times

- `count`: report number of commits (not a performance issue)
- `len`: report length in words of commit message and commit hash (~20s for 1561 commits)
- `len min`, `len max`, and `len avg`: report minimum, maximum, or average commit message length in words and commit hash (~10-15s for the same)

> Benchmarks run with bash's `time` on my [dotfiles repo](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles)

[A previous implementation](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/cb0c865272d06fce3f1471f798de0bd214ae9c57/links/bin/git-cstat#L1) using for-loops had similar performance.

Obviously, the algorithms are *O(n)*. They are still too slow for every-day usage.

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

USAGE='[-h] (count | len [min|max|avg]) [rev-list options]

Display commit statistics
Filter commits based on [rev-list options]'
SUBDIRECTORY_OK=true

# source git-sh-setup for some helpers
set +u
source "$(git --exec-path)"/git-sh-setup
set -u

SIZER=(
  wc
  # count words
  -w
)

size() {
  local commit="$1"
  git log "$commit" -1 --format=%B | "${SIZER[@]}" | tr -d ' '
}

commits_list() {
  command=(
    git
    rev-list
    # start somewhere
    --all
  )
  if (($# > 0)) ; then
    command+=("$@")
  fi
  "${command[@]}" 2>/dev/null
}

commit_count() {
  commits_list "$@" | wc -l | tr -d ' '
}

commit_len() {
  commits_list "$@" |
    while read c ; do
      size "$c" | tr -d '[:space:]'
      printf ' %s\n' "$c"
    done
}

commit_len_min() {
  commit_len "$@" |
    sort -n |
    head -n 1
}

commit_len_max() {
  commit_len "$@" |
    sort -rn |
    head -n 1
}

commit_len_avg() {
  local num=0
  {
    printf '%s\n' '5k'
    while read c ; do
      ((++num))
      size "$c"
      ((num >= 2)) && printf '%s\n' '+'
    done < <(commits_list "$@")
    printf '%s\n' "$num" '/p'
  } | dc
}

main() {
  (($# >= 1)) || usage
  case "$1" in
    count) commit_count "${@:2}" ;;
    len)
      if (($# >= 2)); then
        case "$2" in
          max|min|avg) commit_len_"$2" "${@:3}" ;;
          *) commit_len "${@:2}" ;;
        esac
      else
        commit_len "${@:2}"
      fi
      ;;
    *) usage ;;
  esac
}

main "$@"
```

Shell scripts being hard to profile, I've been unable to identify the bottleneck (though `commit_len` seems like a good place to start).

I run `shellcheck` regularly.

Comment: Some primitive profiling of bash scripts may be possible by tracing with `PS4='\t'` or similar.  That can identify commands that take over a second.

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for the tip. Turns out I'm `size`ing about 61 commits/s, so at ~1600 commits this takes 26s!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. `shellcheck` should give you a few suggestions. I won't mention things I expect it to find.
2. Uppercase names are by convention only used for exported variables.
3. `SUBDIRECTORY_OK` is unused. If it's a magic variable this probably should be mentioned.
4. `SIZER` is only used once, so it should be inlined.
5. `wc -w` 8.30 from GNU coreutils, at least, does not output any spaces, so `tr -d ' '` might be unnecessary.
6. `(($# > 0))` would usually be written `[[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]`.
7. Throwing away standard error means the script will be harder to debug. If there's *specific* output there you want to hide you can use `cmd 2> >(grep -v … >&2)`
8. <strike>`commit_len` is slow because for each commit you run a `git` command & more to count the number of commits *before* it. Which means you traverse the Git history N times. I think you'll get the same result by running `size "$1"`.</strike>
9. You can use `shift` to simplify things like `"${@:2}"` to just `"$@"`.
10. `dc` is not a tool I'm familiar with, but it will certainly be faster to count using something like `awk` to gobble the whole stream in one command. [`while read` is actually surprisingly slow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/3645).

Comment: 3) see `man git-sh-setup`. 5) `wc -w somefile` gives `      92 Desktop/cs.txt
` on my machine (note the leading spaces). 6) But `>` is more readable than `-gt`. 8) `size` only counts the size of a single commit (`log -1`)--if there were a way to log all commits with their message sizes, that would be the fastest. 10) `dc` is a stack-based calculator. That said, if I could use `size` in an awk invocation, that would be a considerable improvement (I could even fix `commit_len` then).

Comment: I did manage to convert `commits_list` to awk, which helped. `commit_avg` was also easy. The result is incredible.

Comment: 5) Try it with standard input instead of a file. Good to hear `awk` helped!

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to drastically improve the performance by combining awk with some creative formatting: now that everything is awk, the script flies under 0.3s for even my ~1600 commits.

#### Result

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

USAGE='[-h] (count | len [min|max|avg]) [rev-list options]

Display commit statistics
Filter commits based on [rev-list options]'
SUBDIRECTORY_OK=true

# source git-sh-setup for some helpers
set +u
source "$(git --exec-path)"/git-sh-setup
set -u

commits_list() {
  command=(
    git
    log
    --pretty'='format:$'\a%n%H\t%s %b'
    # start somewhere
    --all
  )
  if (($# > 0)) ; then
    command+=("$@")
  fi
  "${command[@]}" |
    awk '
      /'$'\a''/ && NR != 1 { printf "\n"; next }
      { printf "%s ", $0 }
      END { printf "\n" }
      '
}

commit_count() {
  git rev-list --all --count "$@"
}

commit_len() {
  commits_list "$@" |
    awk -F$'\t' '{ print split($2,_," "), $1 }'
}

commit_len_min() {
  commit_len "$@" |
    sort -n |
    head -n 1
}

commit_len_max() {
  commit_len "$@" |
    sort -rn |
    head -n 1
}

commit_len_avg() {
  commit_len "$@" |
    awk '
      { sum += $1 }
      END { print sum/NR }
    '
}

main() {
  (($# >= 1)) || usage
  case "$1" in
    count) commit_count "${@:2}" ;;
    len)
      if (($# >= 2)); then
        case "$2" in
          max|min|avg) commit_len_"$2" "${@:3}" ;;
          *) commit_len "${@:2}" ;;
        esac
      else
        commit_len "${@:2}"
      fi
      ;;
    *) usage ;;
  esac
}

main "$@"
```